# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: entities.Cliente.pagamenti[entities.Pagamento]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've the below error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.generaListaClienti] in context with path [/ListaClienti] threw exception
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: entities.Cliente.pagamenti[entities.Pagamento]
```

I've read all questions/answers about this error, but i don't find those errors in my code..

This is my first class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clienti")
public class Cliente {

private String nome;
private String cognome;
private String email;
private String codiceFiscale;
private Set<Pagamento> pagamenti;


@Column(name="nome", length=25, nullable=false)
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@Column(name="cognome", length=25, nullable=false)
public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}

@Id
@Column(name="email", length=30, nullable=false)
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name="codiceFiscale", length=25, nullable=false)
public String getCodiceFiscale() {
    return codiceFiscale;
}

public void setCodiceFiscale(String codiceFiscale) {
    this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
}   

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Pagamento> getPagamenti() {
    return pagamenti;
}

public void setPagamenti(Set<Pagamento> pagamenti) {
    this.pagamenti = pagamenti;
}

}
```

This is my second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pagamenti")
public class Pagamento {

private String id_pagamento;
private String emailCliente;
private String causale;
private String dataPagamento;
private int quota;  
private Cliente cliente;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_pagamento", length=10, nullable=false)
public String getId_pagamento() {
    return id_pagamento;
}

public void setId_pagamento(String id_pagamento) {
    this.id_pagamento = id_pagamento;
}

@Column(name="emailCliente", length=30, nullable=false)
public String getEmailCliente() {
    return emailCliente;
}

public void setEmailCliente(String emailCliente) {
    this.emailCliente = emailCliente;
}

@Column(name="causale", length=55)
public String getCausale() {
    return causale;
}

public void setCausale(String causale) {
    this.causale = causale;
}

@Column(name="dataPagamento", length=30, nullable=false)
public String getDataPagamento() {
    return dataPagamento;
}

public void setDataPagamento(String data) {

    final String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    final String newFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    Date oldDate;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);

    try {

        oldDate = dateFormat.parse(data);
        dateFormat.applyPattern(newFormat);
        this.dataPagamento = dateFormat.format(oldDate);        
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {

        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
}

@Column(name="quota", length=20, nullable=false)
public int getQuota() {
    return quota;
}

public void setQuota(int quota) {
    this.quota = quota;
}   

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Cliente.class)
@JoinColumn(name="email", nullable=false)
public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

}
```

And this is my hibernate file configuration:

```
  <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

  <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>    
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/lista_clienti</property>     
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <mapping class="entities.Cliente"/>
  <mapping class="entities.Pagamento"/>

  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

I've add @Entity-annotation to both class and i've insert mapping class on hibernate.cfg file..

All users that ask a solution for this error forgot one of these things.. but not me. 
So i don't understand what is the problem..

I've also added Annotation Class on all methods, for example:

```
public List<Cliente> getListaClienti() {

    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Cliente.class);
    ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Cliente> clienti = (List<Cliente>) session.createQuery(
      "FROM Cliente c ORDER BY c.cognome ASC").list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return clienti;
}
```

In particular i've this error when i try to call this method "getListaClienti()", but i don't think that error is in method, because first of implements @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations this method worked. (But first, without this annotation i couldn't add more "Pagamento", but only 1, so i need use that annotation).

I hope that you can help me! thanks!

Comment: Make sure you don't have an old copy of `entities.Pagamento` somewhere on the classpath.

Comment: No, i haven't. However i've solved. I had forgot to annoted also "Pagamento" class on method (.addAnnotationClass), thanks however.